# Is there any "forgiven null-forgiving operator" warning facility?

Tags: c#, nullable, static-analysis

Consider this not-so-safe snippet:

```
private object? _obj;

private void Dummy()
{
    if (this._obj == null)
    {
        this.Create();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(this._obj!.ToString());  //note the null-forgiving operator
}

private void Create()
{
    this._obj = new object();
}
```

Although the `_obj` field is clearly guaranteed to be not-null, the checker is not able to understand it. A solution to clear the warning is adding the null-forgiving operator, although it is something that I wish to avoid, or use sparingly.

The revised snippet leads to a safer pattern, and full-checkable code:

```
private void BetterDummy()
{
    this._obj ??= this.BetterCreate();
    Console.WriteLine(this._obj!.ToString());
}

private object BetterCreate()
{
    return new object();
}
```

However, I may forget to remove the `!` from where it is (suppose there are many places like this one). That operator inhibits the checking on that point, so I'd like to set the code at the best.

I wonder if there is an option to highlight/warning the "no-more useful" null-forgiving operators, in order to quickly find and remove them from the code.

Comment: Since `_obj` is a field and not a local property what's guaranteeing that another thread is not nulling the field between your guaranteed `null` assignment and the `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: @Knoop you're right. My original code is truly safe because there's a semaphore locking it. However, I meant "safer" respect to the first snippet.

Comment: "truly safe" sadly that is not true. a `semaphore` only works if everyone plays nice. Even if you force it through properties etc people could still cheat and access the `private` backing field through reflection. Guarantees are a very complicated thing, it seems you have found a scenario where the compiler seems a bit confused (doesn't warn to remove it but also doesn't warn to add it if it's removed), but imo the correct way would not be to tell you to remove it because there is no complete guarantee in this scenario, even with a semaphore.

Comment: search ```!.``` in your project?

Comment: @Knoop don't focus on concurrency or similar: static checking does not take in accoun that. I'm talking about that, not the thread-safety: the above is just an example, but it could be completely different.

Comment: @MichaelMao sure, but I wonder if the static analyzer would offer something smarter than brutally seeking text, and checking "manually" every single occourrence.

Comment: I know that Resharper will highlight usages of the operator where they are not needed.  And it's possible to do a refactor to remove the unneeded ones.

Comment: @juharr that sounds very interesting! I will try on a sample project, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> Although the _obj field is clearly guaranteed to be not-null

But it is not. As @Knoop pointed out, there is no guarantee that some other thread won't affect your object between return from the call to `Create` and its evaluation.

First thing I'd suggest is making your field non-nullable. I can't see any other methods, but the ones you have provided clearly imply that the value should not be null.

If you don't want to allow the potentially unsafe `!.`, why not use a safer `?.`:

```cs
private void EvenBetterDummy()
{
    this._obj ??= this.BetterCreate();
    Console.WriteLine(this._obj?.ToString());
}
```

or, if you have a default value in mind:

```cs
private void EvenBetterDummy()
{
    this._obj ??= this.BetterCreate();
    Console.WriteLine(this._obj?.ToString() ?? "oops, that one 's a null");
}
```

Comment: This is using the nullable flag (otherwise `object?` makes no sense for the `_obj` field. So `BetterCreate` is actually guaranteed not to return `null`.

Comment: this code is okay, but does not answer to my question. Don't think the actual nullability, but focus on a way to find the null-forgiving operators.

Comment: @MarioVernari I don't think I quite understand your question then. Could you, please, edit it to make it clearer what specifically you are concerned with? Is it specifically that you are looking for a way to find "!.", removal of which does not cause a warning?

Comment: I think the comment of @Knoop says enough. The static checking doesn't take in account concurrency, but let's imagine it would do, and I'd like to have hints on it. Now, *with* the null-forgiving, I'd have an "everything all right", but *without* the analisys will alert that the field "may be null". I want this! So, I want to find the null-forgiving operators that lead a dangerous code, then remove them (when possible, of course).

Comment: @MarioVernari I think you might be missing a point when @Knoop mentions thread safety. Compilers and code-analysis tools can not guarantee that the nullable object is not null, other than do a complete check of your entire codebase, which is waaaaay too broad of a task for a compiler/ca-tool and will require immediate re-checking of the entire solution the moment you change anything, anywhere. The only way to ensure that `!.` is not needed is to make your object non-nullable, so the compiler knows not to allow setting it to null.